# How to represent an array in UML class diagram for Kotlin?

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, uml

I  have the following Kotlin class:

```
class Student {

  private val courses: Array<String> = Array(30) {""}
  
  private val grades: IntArray = IntArray(30)

}
```

I am trying to create a UML class diagram for this Kotlin class. I am confused about the way to model the array attributes courses and grades.

Which of these UML representations is correct?

1.

```
-courses: Array<String>[30]
-grades: IntArray[30]
```

2. 

```
-courses: Array<String>(30)
-grades: IntArray(30)
```

3. 

```
-courses: String[30]
-grades: Int[30]
```

Comment: Unless you want to produce a general (like Pseudo Code) UML diagram, you should use the data structures (or primitives, if present) of the programming language you use for that project. Since Kotlin does not have any primitives `int[]` seems inappropriate for a UML class diagram of a Kotlin project.

Comment: My source code is Kotlin, so should I not put my datatype based on Kotlin in uml?

Comment: Can i use Java data type for Kotlin in uml class?

Comment: Use the UML notation and leave the rest to the coder reading the diagram. They will know how to handle it. Generally, UML is ignorant to prg-languages. So you keep it on an abstract level. Coders can do the transformation on the fly - even from UML to other prg-lannguages than you initially targeted.

Comment: I don't fine my answer, please expliane more.

Comment: What I was trying to say is, if you paint a class diagram for a Kotlin project, then use data types from Kotlin (e.g. `+ myArray: Array<Int>`) and when you do the same thing for Java use Java types (e.g. `+ myArray: int[]`)

Comment: If you need to be strictly UML compliant, then the type shall be `Integer[*]`.

Comment: @deHaar I know that in the case of Int[], the size of the array can be specified as Int[30]. However, I'm unsure about how to indicate the size of the array using the Array<Int> notation.

Comment: OK, in that very special case I would even use an `IntArray` instead of an `Array<Int>` and that can be dimensioned via constructor: `IntArray(5)`. See [Kotlin basic types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html), the equivalent of Java primitives in Kotlin. If you stick to an `Array<Int>`, use its constructor, too: e.g. `Array<Int>(20)`. Both options contain all the information needed in a class diagram: name, type, type of content and dimension.

Comment: Voted to reopen because the question this was supposedly a duplicate of was entirely different than this question. However, this question might be off-topic for being opinion-based.

Comment: A Java `int[]` is a Kotlin `IntArray` and a Java `Integer[]` is a Kotlin `Array<Int>`. So, it depends if you want to get into the weeds of primitives vs. non-primitives in your diagram or not. Usually, Lists are preferred to arrays anyway, but I would expect most use cases for a UML to not be so specific about the implementation details.

Comment: @deHaar your approach does not work in a consistent manner in UML.  Because a class `A` having a property  `p:B[0..30]`  is equivalent to a class A being associated with class  B, where the B end is owned by A and its mutiplicity is 0..30.  Both notations are compatible with an `array<B>`. While you would not often use the second notation for arrays of ints or of strings, it is very common with arrays of other types. Your notation with language specific containers would not work with the asocitive notation.

Answer (score 3):

In UML there is no concept of an array. Instead there are properties that have a multiplicity. With this you can specify the number of allowed elements and their ordering and uniqueness. An array defines an ordering, but doesn't require the elements in it to be unique. So it will be specified like this:

`property1:Integer[10..30]{ordered, non unique}`.

This would be shown in the attributes compartment of a class.

How this is translated into a textual notation of a programming language is up to the code generator and should be of no concern to the modeler.

Of course, it might make sense to define the specific primitive datatypes of your programming language, so that readers of the diagram see familiar types. Alternatively you can define a mapping from the predefined UML primitive types.

Comment: Very clear answer. When you write "define the specific primitve datatypes", do you lean a language specific profile?

Comment: Please revirw my question, I was imporove it.

Comment: @Christophe No, a profile would not be the right place. It would be a model library. The primitive datatypes of the UML are also defined in a library.

Comment: @AliDehkhodaei The third option is correct UML (except that the UML datatype is called `Integer`)

Comment: @AliDehkhodaei the key difference here is semantic. When you write IntArray(30) in kotlin, it means that there is 1 property of type array, whereas in UML Interger[30] means that each instance is linked ("associated") with 30 integers (i.e. how it is implemented does not matter). If you want to keep UML semantics (because in the end, what matters for you is that there are 30 grades) but give a hint how the association /multiplicity is ilplemented, you could use a language specific stereotype to suggest the container/collection type to be used (e.g. «IntArray»)

Comment: @Christophe So all three options are correct?

Comment: @AliDehkhodaei not really: 1) says you have 30 arrays (not an array of 30 elements);  2) would be ok, if you would define the langage's primitive types as Axel explained. However no known multiplicity in uml; 3) is correct and accurate as Axel explained. This one could be enriched with a stereotype as explained in my previous comment.